indirection require pointer operand ('int' invalid) issue with image filter program
I'm working on a filter program with one function swapping the pixels and i'm having trouble understanding why it's giving me the indirection pointer bug.
From what i understand, I'm creating a temporary variable that's storing the first corresponding rgb value in the temporary variable, assigning the value of the last pixel in the first, then assigning the first value to the last pixel. Is there something i'm misunderstanding regarding pointers?

void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
      for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= width / 2; j++)
        {

            // assign corresponding values to temporary storage
            int tempGreen = *image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            int tempRed = *image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            int tempBlue = *image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            // assign last pixel value to first pixel
            *image[i][j].rgbtGreen = *image[i][width-j].rgbtGreen;
            *image[i][j].rgbtRed = *image[i][width-j].rgbtRed;
            *image[i][j].rgbtBlue = *image[i][width-j].rgbtBlue;

            // assign first pixel value to las pixel
            *image[i][j].rgbtGreen = tempGreen;
            *image[i][j].rgbtRed = tempRed;
            *image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempBlue;

        }
    }
    return;

This is the terminal error I receive
helpers.c:55:29: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
            int tempGreen = *image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: helpers] Error 1


Why are you using *image instead of image?

* is used for dereferencing pointers. image[i][width-j].rgbtGreen is not a pointer.

Unrelated, but for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) is wrong with image[height][width]; the highest row is index height-1 so the last iteration of this loop runs off the end.  Make it i < height.

And a similar bug using width-j as a column index when j could equal 0.

You actually don't need the dereference operator * anywhere at all in this function.  Can you carefully explain your logic behind wanting to do so? Maybe then it will be possible to see the root cause of your confusion.

I'm following the cs50 online course and in the description, it said that i should look back to how they swapped numbers (1 2 -> 2 1) in the course lecture so based on that, i presumed i was needing to use a pointer since i didn't want to have a pass by value situation.

When they swapped numbers they probably used a signature like that: void swap (int *a, int *b). Your signature is different: RGBTRIPLE image[height][width] You don't have an extra * there.


Is there something i'm misunderstanding regarding pointers?

Apparently so.  Probably at least two things.
That you are writing expressions such as *image[i][j].rgbtGreen suggests that you know that the RGBTRIPLE image[height][width] in the function's parameter list actually declares image is a pointer, not as an array.  But you don't seem to recognize that that does not affect how you access elements.
The indexing operator [] operates on pointers in the first place (not arrays), and does the relevant dereference.

When you index into a variable declared as an array, you actually get an operation on the pointer to which that array decays.

When you pass such a variable to a function, you actually pass the pointer to which the array decays.

Supposing that the corresponding parameter is correctly typed, when you index into the passed (pointer) value, you are already working with the pointer to which the array decays.


You also don't seem to recognize that unary * has lower precedence than postfix operators such as the indexing operator and member selectors.  Thus,
*image[i][j].rgbtGreen means the same as *(image[i][j].rgbtGreen).  If you needed to derference the pointer before operating on the result then you would need to use parentheses to override the default operator precedence.
It looks like you just want to drop all those * operators.  For example:
            int tempGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            int tempRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            int tempBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;


but will that prevent it from being a pass by value situation? I've dropped the * but the image hasn't reflected what so ever.

I have figured out why it wasn't being reflected, i was trying to access the last pixel (ex 44) in the array but forgot to account for an array being width - 1 so the last pixel is actually 43 in the array. Thank you to everyone who took the time to help!
